# MYSQL - Group Contact rows with records NOT IN

Tags: mysql

My case looks simple but i'm messing around with this..

I have 4 tables: User, Macros, Categories, and another one that relate users with categories. One Macro have many Categories.

What i need, is a query that based on the Macro, get the users and the Categories where user is NOT IN.

Example: I have a macro named VEICULES, with categories CAR,TRUCK and Motorcycle. User José is on category CAR and User Julio on category CAR and TRUCK, so my query should return:

```
José | TRUCK,Motorcycle
Julio | Motorcycle
```

Tables:
prd_users

```
 id   |  name  | Email
 ---------------------------
 1    |  José  | jose@email.com
 2    |  Júlio | julio@email.com  
 3    |  André | andre@email.com
```

cat_macros

```
 macro_id |  macro_name  
 -----------------------
 1        |  Veicules  |
```

cat_categories

```
 category_id |  category_name | macro_id  
 ---------------------------------------
 1           |  Cars          |  1
 2           |  Trucks        |  1
 3           |  Motorcycles   |  1
```

prd_tr_rabbit_catg

```
 id |  category_id | tasker_user_id  
 ---------------------------------------
 1  |  1           |  1
 2  |  1           |  2
 3  |  2           |  2
```

I'm stucked on just getting the categories where the user already is ..

```
  SELECT prd_users.id, prd_users.name, 
  prd_users.email,cat_macros.macro_name as macro, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(cat_categories.category_name SEPARATOR ', ') as in_categories 
  FROM prd_users 
  INNER JOIN prd_tr_rabbit_catg ON prd_tr_rabbit_catg.tasker_user_id = prd_users.id
  INNER JOIN cat_categories ON cat_categories.category_id = prd_tr_rabbit_catg.category_id
  INNER JOIN cat_macros ON cat_macros.macro_id = cat_categories.macro_id
  WHERE cat_macros.macro_id = '45'
  GROUP BY prd_users.id;
```

Comment: You should add some sample data to your question.  I'm not sure you will get an answer just based on what you posted above.

Comment: Thank you for the tip @TimBiegeleisen, added some tables to the question

Comment: There's no x here

Comment: what u mean @Strawberry ?

Comment: You can't ask that AND edit the question ;-)

Comment: I realized later @Strawberry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem it's necessary to create a list of all users joined with all categories for the given macro category. This can be done with a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM prd_users u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT m.macro_id, m.macro_name, c.category_name, c.category_id
            FROM cat_macros m
            JOIN cat_categories c ON c.macro_id = m.macro_id) c
```

This can then be `LEFT JOIN`ed to the `prd_tr_rabbit_catg` table and by selecting those rows where there is no matching entry in the `prd_tr_rabbit_catg` table, we can find the users who don't have an entry for the given category:

```
SELECT c.macro_name, u.id AS user_id, u.name, u.Email, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name) AS missing_cats
FROM prd_users u
CROSS JOIN (SELECT m.macro_id, m.macro_name, c.category_name, c.category_id
            FROM cat_macros m
            JOIN cat_categories c ON c.macro_id = m.macro_id) c
LEFT JOIN prd_tr_rabbit_catg x ON x.tasker_user_id = u.id AND x.category_id = c.category_id
WHERE x.id IS NULL
  AND c.macro_id = 1
GROUP BY c.macro_name, u.id
```

For your sample data, this gives:

```
macro_name  user_id     name    Email               missing_cats
Veicules    1           José    jose@email.com      Motorcycles,Trucks
Veicules    2           Júlio   julio@email.com     Motorcycles
Veicules    3           André   andre@email.com     Cars,Motorcycles,Trucks
```

**Update**

To exclude users who don't have any of the categories, add a `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cat_categories WHERE macro_id = 1)
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726440/18)

Comment: Thanks @Nick, it works like a charm. How can i exclude users that are not in any category of the selected macro ? In this case, André should not be on the list.

Comment: @RicardoSantos see my edit. This works, I'm going to try and think of a better solution. If I do I'll edit my post again.

Comment: Sorry late answer, thought that i marked this as correct days ago ! Did it now, thank you Nick!